# JS to hide one div if another is present

Tags: javascript

I can only target with a class and need to add a "data-shipping-method" parameter to the class. Here's what I'm trying...

```
    if (document.getElementsByClassName('div.radio-wrapper[data-shipping-method="shopify-Free%20FedEx%20Ground-0.00"][0]')) {
document.getElementsByClassName('div.radio-wrapper[data-shipping-method="shopify-FedEx%20Ground-19.00"][0]').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

But console says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'visibility' of undefined"

Comment: The element does not exist at the time you're running this code. Ensure that the element exists before changing its visiblity, and ensure you're using the correct selector.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a list of elements not a single element. So you to iterate through each element using loop.

Comment: Note that `getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements.

Comment: I wrapped my code in "window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {" but still get the same error. As to getElementsByClassName returning an array, that's why I have [0] after the element.

Comment: I had the [0] for the array in the wrong place. Fixing it took care of the error, but the div is still not being hidden. I wrapped my code in "window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {" to make sure the element was in the DOM. Thoughts?

Comment: The div is still not being hidden. I wrapped my code in "window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {" to make sure the element was in the DOM. Thoughts?